# Nginx shows public directory content instead of executing Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, http-status-code-403

I am trying to execute my Rails Application on Nginx and Passenger but it shows the public directory content instead of executing the application.

```
server {
    server_name 104.236.218.36;
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/noise/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_spawn_method smart;
    rails_env production;
    autoindex on;
}
```

If i remove `autoindex on;` i am getting the following error.

```
2015/02/02 06:16:06 [error] 13528#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/noise/public/" is forbidden, client: 122.178.204.27, server: 104.236.218.36, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", ho$
```

Answer (score 0):

The config you show works ok for me, but maybe you have something else set wrong outside the system scope.

You could also specify the Rails app directory try adding:

```
passenger_app_root /var/www/noise;
```

Comment: where should i add it?

Comment: Add it anywhere in the server block. Just underneath where you have 'root /var/www/noise/public;' in your code above would be ok